# Spark Scala 2.11.8 Spark HbaseConnector error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to use Spark scala 2.11.8 hbase connector to save the data from kafka stream using jason. But when I am trying to save, I am getting following error. I am using shc connector from hortoworks. My SBT settings are as follows.

Is this connector still supported?

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.0.1" % "provided",
  ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11" % "2.0.1").exclude("org.spark-project.spark", "unused"),
  "org.json4s" % "json4s-native_2.11" % "3.2.10",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9",
   "com.hortonworks" % "shc" % "1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11"
)
```

The error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
    at $line20.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$CTUMhbaseingest$.saveHbase$1(<console>:193)
    at $line20.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$CTUMhbaseingest$.runBusinessLogicAndProduceOutput(<console>:295)
    at $line20.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$CTUMhbaseingest$$anonfun$run$1.apply(<console>:312)
    at $line20.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$CTUMhbaseingest$$anonfun$run$1.apply(<console>:311)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:245)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:244)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your executor or driver classpath. org.apache.spark.Logging is available in Spark version 1.5.2 or lower version. However, I see from your libraryDependencies that you use spark 2.0.1. 
You can check in spark application UI the environment menu, and see the driver & executors classpath.